# Problems upgrading VS2008 to VS2010 with Managed and Unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, managed-c++, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have a VS2008 Professional solution that I tried to convert to VS2010 Professional (RTM from MSDN download) today and I am experiencing some problems with some unmanaged and managed C++ DLLs that are referenced by a C# application.

The C# application is set to target .NET 3.5 (as it was in the VS2008 version) but when I try and compile it I get a lot of warnings like:

> The primary reference "xxxx.dll" could
>   not be resolved because it had an
>   indirect dependency on the .NET
>   Framework assembly "(various assembly
>   names)", Version 4.0.0.0 ... which has
>   a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the
>   version "3.5.0.0" in the current
>   target framework

and ultimately I get a failure to build.

From this I understand that it is a mismatch in .Net framework version.  So I look at the properties of the unmanaged C++ DLL project and under "Common Properties->Framework and References" I can see "Targeted framework: .NetFramework, Version=v4.0"

So I go WTF!?!?!?, why does a pure C++ DLL now target a .Net framework when it sure as hell didn't in the VS2008 version.  I then added on to that exclamation as there appears to be no way to change this.  I also look at the managed C++ and see the same thing: targeting .Net version=v4.0 and again no way to change this at all.

In the C++ General properties there is an entry for "Common language runtime support" and I have set this to "No common language run time support" but that hasn't seem to have done anything.

So I have two questions:

1. Why has my pure C++ DLL now been tagged as targeting a .Net framework?
2. How can I change/remove this targeting?

**Solution**

As per Hans' reply and the link he supplied I now see that I have 3 choices:

1. Stay at VS2008 and everything works
2. Keep both VS2008 SP1 *and* VS2010
   installed so that I can have .Net
   3.5 c# applications and c++ managed code as per the link supplied by Hans.
3. Move everything to VS2010 and move
   to a minimum of .Net 4.0 for all my
   c# apps

I am really annoyed to have to make that choice as MS has deliberately chosen to break functionality when moving from VS2008 to VS2010.  This is not the sort of behavior I expected.  I was expecting to convert the project and have it compile with no issues in the same manner that moving from VS2005 to VS2008 worked.

Fortunately I do have a need to go to .Net 4.0, but I just wasn't expecting to have to do it so soon.

**Update**

I decided to move to .Net 4 framework and encountered problems with referencing managed c++ projects from c# projects.  I was getting errors like the following when trying to add the reference to the c++ managed code project

> A reference to 'myproj' could not be
>   added. An Assembly must have a 'dll'
>   or 'exe' extension in order to be
>   referenced.

Google lead me down the path to "[cli c project cannot be referenced from c project allowing only assembly dll](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526132/cli-c-project-cannot-be-referenced-from-c-project-allowing-only-assembly-dll)" which turned up that there was an extraneous "\" in the output path of the managed c++ project.  The original VS2008 output path was specified as

```
$(SolutionDir)\$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)\
```

But in the VS2010 project the SolutionDir macro has a trailing "\" (or the VS2008 version didn't care about it) giving a path like

```
c:\projects\thisproject\solution\\projectname\configuration\
```

And VS2010 barfed over that path when trying to add a reference to the managed c++ code. My solution was to change the output path to be

```
$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)\
```

And now I am (sort of) happy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your eyes on the ball, the warning you get is for a *managed* C++ assembly.  And the platform target setting for an *unmanaged* DLL is of no consequence, it won't use any .NET references while being built.

Yes, they could not make the platform target setting editable in the C++ IDE, the VS2008 tool chain is required to build C++/CLI assemblies for 3.5.  This [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/framework-multi-targeting-for-vc-projects/) explains the workaround.  You can upvote this [feedback article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/567504/targeting-frameworks-other-than-4-0-with-c-cli-project-and-v100-platform-toolset) if you're unhappy with that.

Comment: Yep that link explains it well.  But now I am more annoyed than anything.

Comment: You are right about my confusion, but I am still a bit put off that the properties of the unmanaged c++ even mentions a .Net framework!